# jquery ajax get with serialize on success get url compiled

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        cache: true,
        data: $('#search-filters-facets').serialize(),
        url: '/layout/set/html_ajax'+target,
        success: function(response) {
//get the url used in the ajax query
        }
})
```

We have a form which is serialized and sent as a GET AJAX request.

The URL is automatically generated with the jquery framework, but is there anyway of accessing it on the success?

Here is an example of the string generated:

```
http://example.com/layout/set/html_ajax/content/search?SearchText=&sleeps=0&filter%5B%5D=attr_accommodation_type____ms%3A%22Inn%22
```

I could write some code to figure this url out, but seen as jquery has already done it seems a waste to do it again..

Comment: what server side are u using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get the url using `this.url`

In your code try this

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    async: true,
                    cache: true,
                    data: $('#search-filters-facets').serialize(),
                    url: '/layout/set/html_ajax'+target,
                    success: function(response) {

                    alert(this.url);  //get the url used in the ajax query

                    }
                });
```